# Protecting CoreML models against piracy

Tags: xcode, coreml

A lot of time goes into building a good machine learning model. When it is then converted to a CoreML model and shipped with an iOS app, supposedly it will be rather easy to extract it from the app that is available for download on the App Store, right?
Any ideas on how to make the extraction at least a little bit harder?

Answer (score 1):

It is really easy to extract the mdoel from the app. Just copy-paste the mlmodelc folder into your own app and you can use the model.

To protect the model you'll have to encrypt it in some way. There is no easy API for this.

You may want to weigh the effort of protecting your models against the risk. What is the likelihood someone will steal your model?

Your model is your intellectual property. If you find that another app is using your model, they are infringing your IP rights and you can sue them for damages. That in itself should already be a deterrent against people stealing your model.

Answer (score 0):

Found a research paper 'Protect your Deep Neural Networks from Piracy' by Mingliang Cheng and Min Wu ([paper on researchgate.net](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330787350_Protect_Your_Deep_Neural_Networks_from_Piracy)) that looks very promising.